# how to align right the text of <option> without use property dir or style direction

Tags: html, css

I want the text of `<option>` align right, then I used property 'dir' or style 'direction'. I got a problem, if I had any symbol at the end of the text,the symbol would change the place. For example:

```css
select{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>test(that's test)</option>
</select>
```

I got '(test(that's test'.Could there has any way to align right the text without use property 'dir' or style 'direction'?

Answer (score 0):

```
option {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: It does. Did you remove select{direction:rtl} before?